# Next.js SSR with dynamic routes for rendering social media app profile pages?

Tags: routes, next.js, server-side-rendering

Is is possible to implement dynamic route in next.js Server Side Rendering fetched data? All examples and explanations of dynamic routes in next I see are set in Static Side Generation...

I am building a social media like application with user profile pages that contains image, video and comment posts, data which is dynamicaly updated by users (profile owner or his followers). Server arquitecture being implemented aside in node.js express, typeorm postgress. Having chosen Next.js for frontend, I understand "Server Side Rendering" is required for dynamically rendering updated data from server to address my app data fetchig demand. But all projects I came accross using dynamic routes are in SSG, usually suited for static data.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I'd recommend a read through [`getServerSideProps` (Server-side Rendering)](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) documentation.

Comment: I already went through all the documentation but can never get a straight answer or example of dynamic routes set in getServerSideProps. I always see same explanation of dynamic routes applyed to GetStaticProps only  :-(

Comment: What part are you struggling with? The route creation is the same as `getStaticProps` but you simply use `getServerSideProps` instead as the data fetching method.

Comment: Well, if that is the case, then thank you so much for the clear feedback. I had a hard time geting it elswhere. Again, thanks!!

Comment: I do not see clearly how to develop a user profile page that consists of  dynamic content, using the [slug].tsx page route file for example, as I only see it applyed to static pages. Not sure how to use the function getSeverSideProps in index.tsx to get all api data (users, followers, likes, profiles already  implemented in backend) and render them in separate pages.  [slug].tsx seems applicable only to GetStaticProps, but ideally I  need it to render pages with frequently updatd posts, comments in real time through it.

Comment: So in that example, would `[slug].tsx` be the profile page, and it would receive a slug, e.g. `some-username` or `some-userid`, that would then be used to retrieve that username's data? If that's the case, then whatever's in that slug needs to be enough to retrieve the data from your API.

Comment: Well, then that s is great!! I assume I may retrieve all data from my backend through  a  getSeverSideProps function, and pass information around to whatever pages, considering  they will be updated in real time. Thanks again.

Comment: Keep in mind that you'd need a `getSeverSideProps` to retrieve the required data on every page that needs that data.

Comment: I just watched a tutorial telling to use a  getServerSideProps only on root index.tsx, so great to know I may use it more than once.  And the profile [slug].tsx pages built with user id may also contain their own api post functions, correct?

Comment: Yes, it can if you want.

Answer (score 1):

in your dynamic route page /pages/[id].js
use getServerSideProps alone without getStaticPaths
this will render the page server side on every request.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post here my example for this specific case, turning a getStaticProps profile page into a getServerSideProps page.

Here is the static page :

```js
// To statically generate dynamic links for each User
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const userSlugs = []
    const request = await getDocs(collection(db, "users")) 
    request.forEach((doc) => {
        userSlugs.push({ 
            params: { id: doc.id },
        })
    })
    return {
        paths: userSlugs,
        fallback: false,
    }
}

// SSG page optimised for SEO
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    // Fetching different type of data from the firestore database

    if (docSnap.exists()) {
        return {
            props: { 
                userId: params.id,
                userData: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(docSnap.data())),
                /// other data
            } 
        }
    } else {
    console.log("No such document!");
    }

}
```

Here is the SSR page :

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) {

    const { id } = params

    const selectedActions = []

    // Getting the user's general data
    const docRef = doc(db, "users", id);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

    // Getting the user's selectedActions
    const req1 = await getDocs(collection(db, "users", id, "selectedActions")) 
    req1.forEach((doc) => {
        selectedActions.push({ 
            id: doc.id, data: doc.data()
        })
    })

    if (docSnap.exists()) {
        return {
            props: { 
                userId: id,
                userData: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(docSnap.data())),
                // other data
            } 
        }
    } else {
    console.log("No such document!");
    }

}
```

Hope it will help :)